# The remainder when $x^2$ $+ ax +4$ is divided by $x-4$ is four times the remainder when the same expression is divided by $x-1$. Find the value of $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

According to my textbook, the answer to this is $-2$.
Isn't this true for any value of a though?

I started by doing the following:

> $4a+20=4x$
>   $a+5  = x$

I'm not sure how they got $-2$ from this, as both equations are equivalent.

Comment: So, what do *you* get when you divide $x^2 +ax+4$ first by $x-1$? and then by $x-4$?

Comment: @GeorgeSandle FWIW if you replace $\,x-4\,$ with $\,x+2\,$ then the answer is $\,a=-2\,$ indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f(x)= x^2 + ax +4$$

You want $$f(4) = 4f(1)$$
$$ f(4) = 20+4a$$

and $$f(1) =5+a$$

Thus $$20+4a=4(5+a)$$ which is valid for every $a$

Therefore $a$ could be any number that we like.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not an answer, but it is too long for a comment.)

Let $f(x) = x^2 + ax + 4$.

I can't make any sense of what you claim to get on dividing $f(x)$ by $x-4$, "$(x-4)(x+4+a)(4a+20)$" or on dividing $f(x)$ by $x-1$, "$(x-1)(x+1+a)(a+5)$".  You also claim the first is the second multiplied by four, which is evidently false.  Why?    The expressions you write must contain "$a^2$"s, but $f(x)$ does not.  \begin{align*}
(x-4)&(x+4+a)(4a+20) \\ &= 4 a x^2 + 20 x^2 + 4 a^2 x + 20 a x - 16 a^2 - 144 a - 320  \\
(x-1)&(x+1+a)(a+5)  \\ &= a x^2 + 5 x^2 + a^2 x + 5 a x - a^2 - 6 a - 5
\end{align*}
It is also straightforward to see that the first is not the second multiplied by four.  In particular, neither $x+4+a = 4(x+1+a)$ nor $x+4+a = x+1+a$.